# Android UI issue after update the ConstraintLayout to 1.1.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

After updating the ConstraintLayout to 1.1.0 the layout is showing white background only.its working fine in constraint-layout:1.0.2'.Please check my XML.In constraint-layout:1.0.2' it show the result. in 1.1.0 is  showing only the outline card view only.plese refer my XML for more details.I want to  update my ConstraintLayout

[image]
  Please check image

-->

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mCardviewPropertytype"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    tools:background="@color/gray_black"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/ImgPropertySelect"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/half_circle"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                tools:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done_white_" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <!-- <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/ImgPropertySelect"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/selection_curve"
             app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->


        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <ImageView
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPropertyType"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/residential_villa_img"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
           />


        <TextView
            tools:text="@string/nearResidentialArea"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_black"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is why the layout worked under 1.0.2 at all. What you see under 1.1.0 is how the layout is really defined. There are a couple of constraints that moved the images and text out of the layout and produced the blank area that you see. I made the corrections to the following XML and all looks OK. (I changed the colors and drawables used since I didn't have ready access to what you used, but you can change them back easily enough.)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    android:id="@+id/mCardviewPropertytype"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    tools:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/ImgPropertySelect"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                tools:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <ImageView
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPropertyType"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            />


        <TextView
            tools:text="Near residential area"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/gray_black"
```

Instead of

```
tools:background="@color/gray_black"
```

Also

Use **`android:text="@string/nearResidentialArea"`**

instead of **`tools:text="@string/nearResidentialArea"`**

Comment: Its also not working in Application.i  hope it wont relate to tools:background=

Comment: @LibinThomas the same code is working with app:cardBackgroundColor

Comment: @LibinThomas i'm using `1.0.2` of constraint-layout

Comment: please  check my question, I  have the problem  only in  ConstraintLayout to 1.1.0, working fine with  1.0.2

Comment: I have `1.1.0` ConstraintLayout, the `app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/gray_black"` is working perfectly

Comment: Check out render problems please

Comment: @SergeyGovyazin agree with u

Comment: @SergeyGovyazin The issue is still there after compile. not render issue. only  happened ConstraintLayout to 1.1.0